# TFS Environment replication from one site to another

Tags: tfs, database-replication, tfs-2005

we are a team who would like to replicate the TFS from one site into another site. Both are in different domain and cannot communicate in any means. Please suggest the best practices of the same.In addition I am also looking for a standalone tool to give me a detailed report of the TFS environment(which includes the work-items, etc) along with the SQL server attached to it. The intention is to replicate the same environment so that a full backup goes through fine.

Comment: What is the purpose? Disaster Recovery or having remote teams working on the same data?

Comment: Its moving the data from one company to other

Comment: So you want to know how to implement a proper backup/restore? Is this a one-shot or must be done periodically, at what frequency?

Comment: Yes we need to perform a proper backup.Its a one shot operation and not periodic.

Comment: Is this the process? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to setup a complete clone of your environment in another site, disconnnected from your. Some key points follows:

- You need a proper backup of the current TFS data, see [Backup TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552295.aspx)
- Size the target environment in terms of disk, memory, network, etc.
- Install on the new site a compatible SQL Server version
- Install on the new site the same (or newer) TFS version
- Study the instruction to [Clone TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx) and apply them on the new site
- Plan for changed environment: Active Directory domain, user accounts
- Topology could be different, you have to rebuild you Build and Test infrastructure or, at least, properly remove the old references from the new site

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is not possible.

You will need to put your TFS server somewhere accessible to both locations. I would recommend either VSO (TFS.visualstudio.com) or a custom IAAS instance and domain.